# Changing an update trigger to insert trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am a beginner and studying about trigger to calculate grade of students from this link. [Student_Marks Trigger](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php#MTBU)
The query for *before update* trigger works fine. I was trying to change the trigger a little bit. I want to calculate the Grade after inserting marks of a student. **Hence, *after* trigger instead of *update***. I got stuck.

My query is as follows:

```
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `student_marks` 
AFTER INSERT 
ON student FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN 
SET NEW.Total =NEW.SUB1+NEW.SUB2+NEW.SUB3+NEW.SUB4+NEW.SUB5; 
SET NEW.Percentage = NEW.Total/5;
IF NEW.Percentage >=90 THEN
SET NEW.Grade = 'EXCELLENT';
ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=75 AND NEW.Percentage<90 THEN
SET NEW.Grade = 'VERY GOOD';
ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=60 AND NEW.Percentage<75 THEN
SET NEW.Grade = 'GOOD';
ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=40 AND NEW.Percentage<60 THEN
SET NEW.Grade = 'AVERAGE';
ELSE SET NEW.Grade = 'NOT PROMOTED';
END IF;
END;
$$
```

Comment: student table has Grade field?

Comment: The last column is Grade field.@HienNguyen

Comment: you tried `BEFORE INSERT`?

Comment: It Worked. Thanks@SebastianBrosch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `BEFORE INSERT` instead of `AFTER INSERT` to save the calculated value of the new row. You can't affect the row `AFTER INSERT` because the row is already saved.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `student_marks` 
BEFORE INSERT ON student_marks FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET NEW.Total =NEW.SUB1+NEW.SUB2+NEW.SUB3+NEW.SUB4+NEW.SUB5; 
    SET NEW.Percentage = NEW.Total/5;

    IF NEW.Percentage >=90 THEN
        SET NEW.Grade = 'EXCELLENT';
    ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=75 AND NEW.Percentage<90 THEN
        SET NEW.Grade = 'VERY GOOD';
    ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=60 AND NEW.Percentage<75 THEN
        SET NEW.Grade = 'GOOD';
    ELSEIF NEW.Percentage>=40 AND NEW.Percentage<60 THEN
        SET NEW.Grade = 'AVERAGE';
    ELSE 
        SET NEW.Grade = 'NOT PROMOTED';
    END IF;
END;
$$
```

You also need to change the table name for the `TRIGGER` (use `INSERT ON student_marks` instead of `INSERT ON student`).

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38dbc736d18e824447f6aa1a02f8d7aa)